# Translation is missing in app not in console

Tags: symfony, symfony4

So I run a website with hundreds of translations, everything was working fine since I've got this one file (security.fr.yml) that won't get translated in production state ONLY (works in local dev env).

In the backend interface I can see that **error.email.exists** didn't get translated and that its translation is **MISSING** :

[image]
[image]

So I've tried to debug that and ran the command `php bin/console debug:translation fr --domain=security` which gave me this result where translation is not missing anymore but just **UNUSED** :

[image]

My **framework.yaml** config has these values for **all of my environments**:

```
framework:
    default_locale: fr
```

The error message is displayed this way

```
{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security')|raw }}
```

If anyone has an idea on how to debug this, I don't even know where to look at right now

BTW I'm using **Symfony 4.1.2**

Comment: Did you only copy the file or also rebuild the caches? In PROD mode Symfony does not read the file directly. Instead the `bin/console cache:clear` creates a cached version that is used.

Comment: the classical error I could imagine would be, that the security.yaml is only readable for your console user but not your web user, also: caches.

Comment: thanks @Jakumi looked like I had to rebuild cache logged as the right user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who came across the problem, I was building cache the wrong way,

had to log as the right user :

```
sudo -u <my-www-user> php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```